# Excel Auto Customize Status Bar not summing up

Tags: excel, sum, toolbar

All,

I am using MS Excel 2016. While highlighting a particular column MS Excel doesn't sum up values in the toolbar. I have checked the setting and sum and other values have been check marked. My column is Text format but changing it to any other format such as Number or General doesn't help.

Any hints/ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

At the the lower left hand corner of the Green excel border there is a word "Ready". Point mouse-right click-check "Sum" (this is about 75% down the drop down menu

Comment: Did you read the question? This part: `I have checked the setting and sum and other values have been check marked`

Comment: Apologies that I have missed that. Do you see a "Ready" at the bottom status bar?

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can't "add text together", so you need to get the affected cells back into a value.

**Changing the cell's Number Format** *(to Number or General for example)* sets the "data type" for new  values entered *after* that point, but **doesn't automatically change how *existing data* is stored.**

You said you're not getting a `Sum` total... what about `Count`?  If the feature is working but it's just an incorrect data type that can't "sum", it should still be showing a `Count` of cells.

This seems to happen more in complex multi-user workbooks, because one user's accidental keystroke can potentially be a pain to diagnose.

I usually just start "fresh cells" for the affected area.

For example, if yours is definitely just one column affected, I would insert a new column next-to or nearby; somewhere that the new column isn't inheriting the same (problem) formatting from the column next to it.

- Then **Copy** the "bad column" and **Paste Values** on top of the "new column".
- Select the column, right click, `Format Cells`, and set your Number format, etc.
- **Copy** the "bad column" again and **Paste Formulas** on top of the "new column".

Basically you can copy everything but the formats of the "bad" column.  (You could also Copy & Paste Formatting from another area of the workbook that *isn't affected* by the issue, or a backup, etc.)

If this is indeed a multi-user workbook, consider setting up Data Validation and/or Protecting parts of the workbook to avoid accidental changes.